# Yodlee error when calling OAuth for Fastlink (getOAuthAccessToken)

Tags: yodlee

I am trying to integrate Yodlee with our app. I have done the first two steps,

1. POST to cob login
2. POST to customer login.

After that using the information received from these steps, I am calling the FastLink OAuth where I am getting the error as below:
{"errorCode":"415","errorDetail":"Token authentication failed for cobrand/user Invalid conversation credentials"}

In this POST, I am passing the following values:

1. cobSessionToken: (cobrandConversationCredentials->sessionToken from the first call)
2. userSessionToken: (userContext -> conversationCredentials -> sessionToken from the second call)
3. bridgetAppId: 10003200

Please let me know where I am doing it incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate the complete signature and have to get the Oauth token using getOauthToken API and have to follow certain steps mentioned [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/FastLink_for_Aggregation/Yodlee_FastLink_Integration_Guide).